# What does frame mean?

Tags: android, frame-rate

I read about frame rate per second. But, unable to understand what is frame and relation with screen refresh/render?

Is it like screen includes layouts which are considered as frames?

Comment: What's this have to do with Android? Movies have frames. A picture is a single frame. A snapshot of time

Comment: This is more like the number of time the screen refreshes per second. The term goes ways back to the movie industry, where it just gives the number of film fields used per second. The higher the framerate the more fluent any animation / movement appears.

Comment: If I render 1 layout file then how many milliseconds of job it will be? And, if it is rendered then should it be updated periodically?

Comment: Also, if my layout for has 1 button only then will it be considered as 1 frame?

Comment: As of Android 4.1, a `View`-based UI is pushed to the screen at 60 frames per second. In other words, every ~16ms, whatever is ready to be drawn gets drawn. What is "ready to be drawn" depends entirely on what we tell Android to draw, directly (e.g., inflating layouts) and indirectly (e.g., populating `RecyclerView` rows in response to users scrolling a list). We "drop frames" when we tie up the main application thread such that it cannot respond to user input and arrange for things to be drawn (e.g., we are loading data on the main thread while the user is trying to scroll the list).

Comment: Okay but how to know list of items which are in state to be drawn and other's are yet to become ready?

Comment: Please watch the Google IO video on Project Butter for Android: https://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE

Answer (score 0):

It means, how many times layout is refreshed per second (not necessarily redrawn, but refreshed). If you have "heavy duty" calculations on main thread, then Android will skip some frames. This is just example to help you understand the topic. Hope it'll help